# SPARQL: find subjects with the same set of triples?

Tags: sparql, rdf, stardog

I am trying to identity Subjects that have the exact same "set" of triples. In this example data, `:Set2` should be identified as the only exact match with `:Set1`, while `:Set1` and `:Set3` are NOT an exact match because of the value `:VAL_E`.

```
@prefix :  <https://www.example.org/Eg#>.

:Set1 :hasValue  :VAL_A, :VAL_B, :VAL_C, :VAL_D .
:Set2 :hasValue  :VAL_A, :VAL_B, :VAL_C, :VAL_D .
:Set3 :hasValue  :VAL_A, :VAL_B, :VAL_C, :VAL_D, :VAL_E .
:Set4 :hasValue  :VAL_A, :VAL_B .
:Set5 :hasValue  :VAL_F, :VAL_G, :VAL_H, :VAL_I, :VAL_J .
```

I have found example SPARQL on StackOverflow that identifies individual triples that match between `:Set1` and the other sets, and even the [number of matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351911/working-with-sparql-lists-in-dotnetrdf-intersection-of-lists/25369706#25369706) , but not how identify an exact match of a set of triples as a whole. I expect a combination of `FILTER NOT EXISTS` and `!SAMETERM` is needed, but I can't get the syntax correct.

UPDATE:
I adapted the SPARQL from @StanislavKralin to find other Sets identical to :Set1. It almost works.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?s2 {
  :Set1 ?p ?o .
  ?s2 ?p ?o .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { :Set1 ?p1 ?o1 . FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s2 ?p1 ?o1 } }
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s2 ?p2 ?o2 . FILTER NOT EXISTS { :Set1 ?p2 ?o2 } } # omits match from :Set3 to :Set1
  FILTER (STR(:Set1) < STR(?s2))
}
```

However, the result of my query includes :Set4, which is incorrect.

```
:Set2
:Set4
```

What am I missing?

**[Update]**
As noted in the comments below, Stanislav provided further explanation and code on the Stardog Community Forum: https://community.stardog.com/t/unexpected-sparql-filter-results/2745/14 , along with additional information from Pavel Klinov explaining Stardog's current behaviour. As you can read there, a ticket has been opened for resolution. Meanwhile, this code provided by Stanislav provides the correct result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s1 ?s2 {
  ?s1 ?p ?o .   
  ?s2 ?p ?o .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?s1 ?p ?o . 
    ?s2 ?p ?o . 
    ?s1 ?p1 ?o1 . 
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s2 ?p1 ?o1 } }
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?s1 ?p ?o . 
    ?s2 ?p ?o .
    ?s2 ?p2 ?o2 . 
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s1 ?p2 ?o2 } }
  FILTER (STR(?s1) < STR(?s2))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested in Apache Jena Fuseki and Ontotext GraphDB:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?s1 ?s2 {
  ?s1 ?p ?o .
  ?s2 ?p ?o .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s1 ?p1 ?o1 . FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s2 ?p1 ?o1 } }
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s2 ?p2 ?o2 . FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s1 ?p2 ?o2 } }
  FILTER (STR(?s1) < STR(?s2))
}
```

**Explanation**

Let `S1` and `S2` be the sets of triples having `:s1` and `:s2` as subjects respectively.
What does `S1 ≡ S2` mean? That means that `S1 ⊆ S2` and `S2 ⊆ S1`.
What does `S1 ⊆ S2` mean? That means that `∀x(x ∈ S1 → x ∈ S2)`.
Unfortunately, there is no something like `∀` ('for all') in SPARQL.
However, one could write `¬∃x¬(x ∈ S1 → x ∈ S2)` instead and use SPARQL's `NOT EXISTS`.
Finally, `x ∈ S1` could be translated as `:s1 ?p ?o`.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52900486/7879193).

Comment: What does your query result look like?  See my edited question above for an attempted adaptation.

Comment: @Tim, my query returns `({?s1→:Set1, ?s2→:Set2})`. Your query returns `({?s2→:Set2})` for me, not `({?s2→:Set2}, {?s2→:Set4})`. Which triplestore are you using?

Comment: I am using Stardog 7. I will post this example data and to their support forum and update here when I get feedback. Thank you for this information!

Comment: OK. I hope, that is a query optimization problem. However, the question is subtle itself, see e.g. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322518229

Comment: @Tim, I've answered there: https://community.stardog.com/t/2745/14. As a workaround, try to duplicate BGP (`?s1 ?p ?o . ?s2 ?p ?o`) inside the outer `NOT EXISTS`s.

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed explanation here and on the Stardog forum. I updated my question with the example code you provided so people can see it directly on SO.